# React Native events do not fire

Tags: reactjs, react-native, events, pointer-events

This is the body of my `render()` method. Why are none of these events firing?

```
return (
  <View
    style={{flex:1}}
    onPointerDown={e => this._events.emit("pointerdown", e)}
    onPointerUp  ={e => this._events.emit("pointerup",   e)}
    onPointerMove={e => this._events.emit("pointermove", e)}
  >
      ...
  </View>
);
```

This is inside my `App.js` file. I've tried replacing the event bodies with `{console.log}` and nothing is printed in my terminal or the web debug page.

Comment: where did you find the onPointerDown/Up/Move thing? This doesn't look like it's gonna work in React Native. You should look into https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system or https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder

Comment: @MarcelKalveram honestly I have no idea, I spent 30 mins searching things like "react native events list" and I never even found that page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These event are not firing because: `onPointerUp`,  `onPointerDown` and `onPointerMove` aren't part of react-native's View props.

If you want to handle touches, check those:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches

or

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#synthetic-touch-events

Comment: onResponderRelease still doesn't fire by the looks of it- I made an alert show up in the render method and it shows up but when I put it as the event handler, nothing happens

Comment: Got it, thanks! For some reason it works with PanResponder.